# There is Something I do not understand about interface

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
```

Hi, I'm working on instagram login,follow etc. I'm using Selenium,ChromeDriver.

There is interfaces named IWebElement and IWebDriver. I'm using its methods.

as far as i know Interfaces cannot contain code.

how can this methods works ?

if this interface implemented, where is it. And how can i find and see codes

My code works but why it works :)

```
 __username.SendKeys(username);
__password.SendKeys(password);
  button.Click();
```

[İmage 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SzwJ.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE38e.png)

Comment: The reason the code works is because at runtime you're not executing the interfaces `IWebElement` and `IWebDriver`; you're executing types that implement those interfaces.  I suspect one of the libraries you're referencing has those types defined.

Comment: The interface isnt the actual method, its just a "contract" to make sure that all implementations follow the same naming and parameters lists.

Comment: @StingyJack yes i know, but how can i find the actual method

Comment: @TümayŞahin - For IWebElement, its whatever `v` is... I cant see that variable cos of the hover text

Comment: If you want to see how any .NET code works (for learning, not plagarism), you can use ILSply (http://ilspy.net/). It will decompile the code to show you what is happening in several .NET languages.

Comment: Ty, i will look..

Comment: V is IWebElement  @StingyJack

Comment: V is not IWebElement. V implements IWebElement.

Comment: I'm still looking for click() and SendKeys() methods.using ILSpy :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code to Selenium is available on GitHub, so you can clone the repo and play around to see how things work.

[Here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ceaf3da79542024becdda5953059dfbb96fb3a90/dotnet/src/webdriver/IWebElement.cs) is the interface for IWebElement.

Looking at [ChromeWebElement](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Chrome/ChromeWebElement.cs), it inherits from [RemoteWebElement](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/650a1ab4fe3f0363cde72d8e0202e61e3f713acd/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebElement.cs), which is what actually implements the concrete [SendKeys function](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/650a1ab4fe3f0363cde72d8e0202e61e3f713acd/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebElement.cs#L289).

ILSpy is pretty invaluable - Drag dll into tree view and then search for things.
[image]